# Cloning fully encrypted SATA disk to larger SSD

Tags: clone

I am using Debian and have fully encrypted disk include /boot partition. I have SATA 320GB disk and planning to buy a SSD. I want to clone my current disk to a new larger SSD.

I found this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/761763/cloning-encrypted-ssd-to-larger-ssd) but it doesn't contain all steps. I am bit confused about expanding disk.

Thanks.

Comment: The manual is pretty straightforward and seeming contains all the steps aside from partitioning. What do you need help with?

Comment: I will do these steps from a live cd right?

Comment: And by the way i couldn't see expand commands for fdisk.

Comment: *I will do these steps from a live cd right?* LiveCD/USB/whatever. Commands for fdisk weren't given because they are dependent on your storage abilities. Also, I prefer to use `gdisk` or even `gparted` (GUI for `parted`) instead of `fdisk`.

Comment: Okay understood. I want to check the steps.

1) Copy all stuff with dd
2) Expand disk size with Gparted
3) decrypt encrypted partition and resize disk with this command (sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdY1 sdY1_crypt
sudo cryptsetup resize /dev/sdY1_crypt)

Is that correct?

Comment: First you 1) partition 2) then copy data 3) then resize it

Comment: I am confused in partition step. Now i will insert new SSD to computer and i won't format the disk. It is unallocated now because just new bought. I will use dd command for copy and resize it with gparted.

I found this (https://jotbe.io/blog/2019/03/how-to-clone-a-luks-encrypted-hhd-to-a-larger-ssd/) thread. Will that work for me?